# I enabled Memory Integrity but cannot disable it again. How to turn it off?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

I have a 5800H/RTX3060 Windows 10 Pro Laptop and I turned Windows Security: Core Isolatio/**Memory Integrity** ON to see how benchmark are affected.

After I'm done I tried to disable it again, but it does not get disabled. I click on it to set it to OFF. I get a notification to restart the PC. After a Restart it is ON, like nothing happened.

Can you help turn it off again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To disable Memory Integrity, run the Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator
and copy-paste the following command, rebooting afterward:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity" /v "Enabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Source:
[Enable virtualization-based protection of code integrity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/device-guard/enable-virtualization-based-protection-of-code-integrity).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with **Windows 11 running on VMware as a virtual machine**. After **enabling Memory Integrity, the entire system became extremely laggy**.

Fortunately, I found a [solution by running the command shared by harrymc above](https://superuser.com/a/1681729/473952).

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity" /v "Enabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Due to laggy system, I was only able to run the command in Safe Mode with Command Prompt.
In case someone may wonder, here's a [useful guide on how to start Windows 11 in Safe Mode with Command Prompt (cmd)](https://is.gd/DEivLq).